# Tag quasi-duplicates in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider a list of strings in columnm A. Each member takes the form `a_delimiter_b`. The list also has quasi-duplicate members `b_delimiter_a`.

How can I select all the relevent entries without the "duplicates?" This is how can I query for entries in the columnn, and for each `a_delimiter_b` exclude `b_delimiter_a`?

**Attempt:**
I am trying to tag the duplicates in another column.

```
=IF(<condition>,"Keep","Delete")
```

I need a good condition that I cannot think up. If I use `VLOOKUP` both the "orginal" and the "duplicate" are taggef. For example if the element is `A1="a_delim_b"`

```
<condition> = ISERROR(VLOOKUP(b_delim_a, <list_range>, FALSE))
```

I can get `"b_delim_a"` by

```
CONCAT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_delim_",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),(2-1)*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1))) & "_delim_" & TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_delim_",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),(1-1)*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1))))
```

This does not work because if `"b_delim_a"` exists, all entries in the list are tagged for deletion.

How can I tag to keep only exacly one instance and tag to delete the other occurances?

[image: FAIL]

Comment: Do you have some sample data with expected returns? Say, a screenshot or even better some markdown samples?

Comment: I added a minimal screenshot, @JvdV.

Comment: I see, thanks. Looks like `COUNTIF` can be handy here, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in `B1` and drag down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,MID(A1,FIND("; ",A1)+2,LEN(A1))&"; "&LEFT(A1,FIND("; ",A1)-1)),"Delete","Keep")
```